# Почему в следующей строке datetime пишется два раза?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
now = datetime.datetime.today()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Первый `datetime` - модуль, который предоставляет классы для обработки времени и даты разными способами.

Второй `datetime` - это класс комбинации даты и времени, который находится внутри этого модуля.

[Здесь можно более подробно почитать об этом](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-datetime.html)